# Where to store the bootloader on a floppy image?

Tags: bootloader, machine-code

I'm going to write and test a bootloader. In order to do this, I am planning to copy the bootloader onto a floppy image file and mount it in a VM.

However, I'm not sure where to put the bootloader's machine code. Does it just get dumped into the first few bytes of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boot sector of the floppy was the first sector. If you're talking about a raw floppy image (1440K), it should be the first 512 bytes of the image file.

From memory, this gets loaded by the BIOS into 7c00:0000 (real mode) and then jumps to that address.

The DOS boot floppies had a 3-byte `JMP` instruction there to jump over the Disk Parameter Block (DPB), which detailed the attributes of the disk. But, if you're in total control of the disk and your boot code, I don't think you need to follow that convention. I don't recall any BIOS' checking what was loaded for validity (though admittedly it was a *long* time ago).

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

its been a VERY long time but if i recall in DOS it was stored in the MBR.  i believe its still the same today

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question, though. Where **in the IMG file** does it get stored?